# How to merge or replace pantone or spot ink in illustrator in one go?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pantone

I have a huge artwork content where i need to relace or merge one pantone with another. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Select All — <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (Windows)
2. Open the Recolor Artwork dialog (**Edit > Edit Colors > Recolor Artwork** or click the Recolor Artwork icon)
3. Use the Assign tab to replace colors. The original colors are on the left, double click the color on the right to select a new color (a new Pantone swatch in your case)

https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/illustrator-recoloring-artwork.html

Answer (score 0):

- Create the other color as a new swatch.
- Then click on it in the swatches panel.
- Press Cmd and click on the font you want to replace.
- From the swatches panel menu select "Merge Swatches"

Taken from https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2484567 - kudos to Monika Gause